# Want to bottle and sell a marinade/sauce

Tags: food-safety

I have a marinade recipe I want to sell to local small stores but I don’t know the logistics of how to make the product last with shelf life and I’ve read about oils causing botulism. I’m not sure where to find this information or how to go about it .

Answer (score 3):

Check the colleges near you as they may have a food incubator program. There are several in Louisiana both affiliated with colleges and privately owned. They have programs to teach you the basics, professors to help answer questions, staff to help take your recipe from small batch to larger quantities, and commercial kitchens for rent.

You can also contact the Department of Health. they were quite helpful when I was starting my company, especially with label reviews.

If you are planning on making an acidified product, you should look into a Better Process Control course. These are offered at some universities (some have online options) and are a requirement of most food incubators. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it's all about how acid/salty, low water is the food 
([Shelf stable acid preserved foods](http://www.foodauthority.nsw.gov.au/_Documents/scienceandtechnical/shelf_stable_acid_preserved_foods.pdf) and [Food Processing for Entrepreneurs Series](https://foodsafety.wisc.edu/assets/GMP_sauces_NebEntre.pdf))

It is also about how the food is packaged, you need to have a sterile environment (as sterile as possible); hot packaging, pasteurization,...

I suggest looking at local regulations for commercial kitchen.